# php-mysql How to select the particular number of the row in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new at this and learning the code.
I want to create the php code which select the particular row.
say 5th row or 6th row any row.
I create the code like this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "test1";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "test1";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM mytable ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0)


 {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["FIELD1"]. " - Name: " . $row["FIELD2"]. " <br>";
    }



} else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

THis code works fine but it give the all data of the table.I want to just select particular row number data.how to do this??

Comment: The sql needs to have a condition applied, such as:
select * from table mywhere id=1

Comment: Using `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0` will give you the first result, `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1` would give you the second one and so one. Though it would be better to make a column `id`. That way you can do `... WHERE id=10` for example.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT n,1 should work. This query will return one row starting at nth record.

Comment: You must have a unique 'id' field for the table. Then call the row with that id.

`$sql = "SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM mytable where id=1 ";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the LIMIT statement, say LIMIT 3,1 to select the 4th row. First number is the starting row, second number is the count of rows to select.

```
$sql = "SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM mytable LIMIT $row_index, 1";
```

will give you row $row_index + 1

Answer (score -2):

You can do it using `WHERE` condition in query as `SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM mytable WHERE id = 1`.

Comment: id is not always sequential. If you delete row with id 3, you will have an order like 1,2,4